# How to implement reCAPTCHA in a current PHP email form

Tags: php, forms

I am new to PHP, but know my way around HTML. I have been asked to implement a reCaptcha form into our site's PHP contact email form. I'm coming up empty. I have signed up and have my site key and secret key, just no idea how to integrate it into our form.

Here is our sites PHP form:

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">You have entered an invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Please enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "yourname@yourdomain.com";

$address = "contact@########.com";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name from your website, their message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name by email, $email or by phone $phone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h2>Email Sent Successfully.</h2>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been sent to us.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Google has a Getting Started page for reCAPTCHA, have you taken a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

First, as a part of your form elements, include reCaptcha:

```
<?php
require_once("location/of/recaptchalib.php");
    $publickey = "yourPublicKeyGoesHere";
    echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
```

in your send_email.php file you can do this:

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    require_once("location/of/recaptchalib.php");
    $timezone = "Asia/Kuwait";
        if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

    $privatekey = "YourPrivateKey";

    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]
                );

    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
        die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
             "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
    } 

    else {
        $sender_name    =   $_POST['sender_name'];
        $sender_email   =   $_POST['sender_email'];
        $query_type     =   $_POST['query_type'];
        $ip             =   $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        $date           =   date("d M Y H:i:s");
        $sender_message =   "Thank You for your message, ".$sender_name."\r\n"."Message was sent from ".$ip."on ".$date."\r\n".$_POST['sender_message'];

        $headers        =   "From: Your Website" . "\r\n" .
                            "BCC: you@yourwebsite.com";
        mail($sender_email,'Email from yourwebsite guest',$sender_message,$headers);

        echo "Message Sent!";
    }
?>
```

This worked for me, and the form looks like this:

[image: reCaptcha Form]

I hope this helps.